# Visual svn diffs from an ssh'd remote server

Tags: macos, svn, diff, command-line-interface

I work at a small company, and we connect to our development environment via SSH for commits and through SMB to just look through the file structure.

Before I commit my code, I want to be able to see a nice GUI Diff of the files that I am committing. I use Coda 2 to program, and unfortunately it's Source Control support is shit and won't detect that the SMB-mounted drive where my development directory is is also an SVN working copy, so all of its SCM tools are totally useless at work.

Anyway, because I am SSH'd in, I can't use the opendiff or diffmerge commands (since they're installed on my local computer and not on the remote server).

I'm wondering if anyone can give me a tip as to how I can call svn diff from the command line, but then look at it in a nice GUI display instead of the textual -/+ notation that SVN gives you on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the preferred GUI tool installed in the server, just tunnel X through ssh like:

```
ssh -X yourworkserver
```

Then just lauch your tool of choice in the server as if it were an X capable terminal.

If your server does not have (the capability of having) the tools, you could always sync the stuff about to be committed to your local machine. E.g.

```
rsync -a --delete --partial --progress --rsh=ssh  username@yourserver:/path/to/code/about/to/be/committed /path/to/the/snapshot/in/your/machine
```

Then run your favourite GUI tool locally. You can add -az to speed the process up by compressing the traffic.

If your server has Ubuntu, have someone with privileges run "sudo apt-get install meld", and use Meld over tunnelled X.

Most decent text editors (e.g. Emacs, Vim, ...) have diff syntax highlighting included in the default configuration and they have text modes too.

Comment: It does not have the necessary apps.

Comment: What OS does the server have? You could have the apps installed unless it is a Windows box.

Comment: It has Ubuntu, but it's a corporate environment and I don't want to ask my boss to install stuff on our dev server unless it's absolutely necessary. What I'd love is a Diff tool that I could just copy and paste the output from svn diff into

Comment: @tigertrussell This whole thing sounds awkward to me. Where do you edit your code? In your local machine? In the server? In your local machine, but on the SMB share (bad idea)? It makes more sense to check out stuff locally, either using the svn+ssh:// protocol or https:// protocol or whatever you use for SVN. Then the whole "diffs there, gui here" problem goes away.

Comment: I believe that your description of a "bad idea" is what we are doing. The purpose for this, I believe, is to allow developers to see their own local copy (we all have firstname.dev.myserver.com) running on a server...

Comment: Having files open over the network has its risks, but I assume you are aware of them. Just to check your configuration, can you see the .svn subdirectories on you SMB share? In some configurations such directories are not shared by Samba and thus also cannot be used.

Comment: No, I cannot. I'll ask the CTO if he can enable them, then maybe Coda will work!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you cannot use svn directly on your SMB share - are the .svn folders not visible at all from the client machine?

Anyway you might have better luck mounting your working directory using [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html) instead of SMB. See also [this link](http://blog.philippklaus.de/2011/07/sshfs-on-mac-os-x-10-6-8-with-fuse4x/) for specific info on OS X.

Comment: I don't understand this response. Firstly, I can't just switch from SMB to SSHFS - this is a corporate environment, and I use SMB to connect to the development server because that's how the company wants it...?

Comment: You talked about ssh. If you can do ssh, you can do sshfs. If you or somebody else doesn't want to, that's another story.

Comment: I just fixed the typo in the answer (ssh instead of svn), sorry.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to avoid using it just because it's not explicitly approved--if I get desparate I'll ask our CTO